# Scaling up a Serverless Web Crawler and Search Engine in aws

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions, amazon-kendra

https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-step-functions-kendra-web-crawler-search-engine

I was referring above link and implementing web crawling on particular website.

I have deployed the stack using command deploy --profile <YOUR_AWS_PROFILE> --with-kendra

but when i am using
crawl --profile <YOUR_AWS_PROFILE> --name lambda-docs --base-url https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ --start-paths /lambda --keywords lambda/latest/dg

it is giving me error:
'/crawl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

in the link it has been shown like "When the infrastructure has been deployed, you can trigger a run of the crawler with the included utility script"
is there any something to install the crawl command.

Answer (score 0):

That should be `./crawl` according to the README of the project.

Your error message also sounds like it's coming from Windows but the crawl script is written in Bash so you may run in to issues unless you switch to Linux/MacOS/BSD (or WSL).